# Type 'Startup' already defines a member called 'Configuration' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I have this on my startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(xx.yy.Startup))]
namespace xx.yy
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

and I have this
Startup.Auth.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

namespace xx.yy
{
    public static class xxAuthentication
    {
        public const String ApplicationCookie = "xxAuthenticationType";
    }

    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = xxAuthentication.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider(),
                CookieName = "ComisionesCookie",
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12), // adjust to your needs
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Howevver it does not compile with this error:

[image]

I use the code from this page
http://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy, but hard to find, the problem is another developer created a startup.cs file with same signature in a different folder in the project structure. Will leave evidence here because it might be useful for another developer

Comment: exactly, in my case there was another startup file in the same project existed in a folder

Answer (score 0):

You could have to constructors members in Startup class like this:

```
public class Startup {

    public Startup(IConfiguration _configuration){
        this._configuration = _configuration;
    }

    private IConfiguration _configuration{ 
        get; 
    }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration){
        // Expose the injected instance locally so we populate our settings instance
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
```